# Advice on Prepared-Statements and Joins

Tags: php, sql, join, prepared-statement

I'm trying to build a back end solution to a web page project for a class i'm taking. The class doesn't cover anything about back end coding so I've had to learn everything myself. I want to understand how to utilize prepared statements and joins in the PHP code below. There are three tables in my database, but i only want back the data from one of them and only sometimes need to reference the other two to hone in my search.

The code currently works as expected, but is vulnerable to sql injection. I'm getting three form inputs from the user: a text input ($_POST["spell_name"]), a select element ($_POST["classList"]), and some checkboxes ($_POST["school"]). It still needs to work when the checkbox sends an empty array (none of the checkboxes are checked) and the select element sends the default value "all".

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM dnd5_spells WHERE ";
     if($_POST["classList"] != "all"){
            $sql .= "spell_id= ANY(SELECT spell_id FROM dnd5_class_spells WHERE class_id = ANY(SELECT class_id FROM dnd5_classes WHERE class_name='{$_POST["classList"]}')) AND";
     };
    $sql .= " spell_name LIKE '%{$_POST["spell_name"]}%'";
    if(!empty($_POST["school"])){
            $sql .= " AND (";
            $spellschools = $_POST["school"];
            $valueLength = count($spellschools);
            for ($x = 0; $x < $valueLength; $x++) {
                    if ($x>0) {
                            $sql.= " OR";
                    };
                    $sql .= " spell_type" . " LIKE" . " '%" . $spellschools[$x] . "%'";
            };
            $sql .= ")";
    };
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

How do i make a prepared statement when i can receive all or none of the possible input values and i don't know what i'm getting ahead of time (in my case sending the form data blank returns the entire table and this is good)? Can i iterate over an array into a prepared statement when the array can either be empty or have multiple values? Should i be concerned about including sections of the sql query when that part of the query isn't needed?

Also, i know my use of ANY could possibly be replaced with a JOIN, but i couldn't wrap my head around it and it's less important to me than figuring out the prepared statement issue.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually prepare anything. The code you show us is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, I believe there is too much text. Could you trim it down a little bit please?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to cut down the text a bit. i'm having a hard time understanding how to implement prepared statements in this case because i can receive all or none of the possible inputs.

Comment: You can build the statement dynamically, based on the number of inputs you have. With PDO, binding dynamic number of parameters is a piece of cake.

Comment: Maybe this article could be helpful to you https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where If not there is plenty of articles on https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples maybe one of them would show you how to do it dynamically.

Comment: Right now your code concatenates a value into the SQL string, so you clearly know how to concatenate strings. Shift your perspective away from concatting values, and towards concatting parameter placeholders instead.. Concatenate a parameter placeholder into the string, then do whatever is needed to assign that placeholder parameter a value... In C# (my "native" language) this would be like `sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE ..."; if(name != null) sql = sql + "AND name = @n"; sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@n", name);` - concat the parameter name (not the value) then add a parameter with that value

Comment: Pin yourself down to one specific question about one specific place you are stuck & give a [mre]. All the things you're asking about are faqs but you need to clearly write multiple concise precise phrasings of each specific question to find them. PS Read an introductory book on SQL. PS Beware that ALL, ANY/SOME & IN treat NULL in a certain way & if relevant find out what that is. PS Please do not inject EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best possible at the time. If you have an answer post it as an answer. If reasonable answers are posted, don't change your question .

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for the advice! It seems that using PDO and constructing my query with prepared statments in mind was the way to go. I think I've got a lot to learn about SQL and back end coding in general but this was a big help. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @x to notify one non-poster non-sole commenter x about a comment. [help] [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found. I needed to use PDO then build my statement as I went with prepared statements in mind, placing `?` where I wanted my input data, and at the same time build an array with the corresponding data values. I doubt it's perfect but it works just as well as my initial code and is less susceptible to SQL injection.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dnd5_spells WHERE ";
    $parameters = [];

    if($_POST["classList"] != "all"){
        $sql .= "spell_id= ANY(SELECT spell_id FROM dnd5_class_spells WHERE class_id = ANY(SELECT class_id FROM dnd5_classes WHERE class_name= ?)) AND";
        $parameters[] = $_POST["classList"];
    };

    $sql .= " spell_name LIKE ?";
    $parameters[]= "%" . $_POST["spell_name"] . "%";

    if(!empty($_POST["school"])){
        $sql .= " AND (";
        $spellschools = $_POST["school"];
        $valueLength = count($spellschools);
        for ($x =0; $x < $valueLength; $x++){
            if ($x>0){
                $sql.= " OR";
            };
            $sql.= " spell_type LIKE ?";
            $parameters[] ="%" . $spellschools[$x] . "%";
        };
        $sql .= ")";
    };

    //bind the peramaters into the prepared statment
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```